# Textbox losing value after another buttons postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

On my page I have 3 textboxes that hold values for Title, Description, Tips and keywords. When I click on a button it inserts the values into the database. When it posts back, the values are staying in the textboxes, and this is what I want.
The next part of the page has textboxes for Question, CorrectAnswer, Wrong1, Wrong2, Wrong3. When I click on the button to insert them into the database, that works, and after the button fires its event I have those 5 textboxes have a text value of null, so I can continue on adding the question and answers.
But when that button causes its postback, the values in the first textboxes disappear, and I don't want that because I have validation on the title textbox, because you can't add any questions and answers without the title in the textbox.
So how do I keep the values in the first textboxes when the second button causes a postback?
Here is the code for the two buttons, and the btnAddQandA is the button that causes a postback..

```
protected void btnAddQuizTitle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    daccess.AddQuizName(tbTitle.Text, taDescription.InnerText, taTips.InnerText, tbKeywords.Text);
    Session["TheQuizID"] = daccess.TheID;
    string myID = (string)(Session["TheQuizID"]);

    int theID = Int32.Parse(myID);

    if (tbKeywords.Text != null)
    {
        string TheKeywordHolder = "";
        foreach (ListItem LI in cblGrades.Items)
        {
            if (LI.Selected == true)
            {
                TheKeywordHolder = TheKeywordHolder + LI.Value + ",";
            }
        }
        daccess.AddQuizKeywords(theID, tbKeywords.Text);
    }

}

protected void btnAddQA_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int theID = (int)Session["TheQuizID"];

    daccess.AddQuizQA(tbQuestion.Text, tbCorrect.Text, tbWrong1.Text, tbWrong2.Text, tbWrong3.Text, theID);
    tbQuestion.Text = null;
    tbCorrect.Text = null;
    tbWrong1.Text = null;
    tbWrong2.Text = null;
    tbWrong3.Text = null;
}
```

and here is my pageload event

```
DataAccess daccess = new DataAccess();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    daccess.CblGradesDS();
    cblGrades.DataSource = daccess.DsCbl;
    cblGrades.DataValueField = "GradeID";
    cblGrades.DataTextField = "Grade";
    cblGrades.RepeatColumns = 8;
    cblGrades.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
    cblGrades.DataBind();

    daccess.CblSubjectsDS();
    cblSubjects.DataSource = daccess.DsCbl2;
    cblSubjects.DataValueField = "SubjectID";
    cblSubjects.DataTextField = "SubjectName";
    cblSubjects.RepeatColumns = 4;
    cblSubjects.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
    cblSubjects.DataBind();

    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These issues are usually caused by control IDs (UniqueIDs to be specific) that do not match before and after the postback. This causes inability of finding values in viewstate. This happens when you modify the controls collection (typically in codebehind) or when you change controls' visibility. It may also happen when you modify IDs before Page_Load event when viewstate is not yet populated. It's good to know how ASP.NET lifecycle works. http://spazzarama.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/aspnet_page-control-life-cycle.jpg

Comment: Thanks, as soon as I read your first sentence about ids, it was a page done with bootstrap and when I read it and looked at my mark up for the cssclass and realized that I had to change it because of their was a conflict between my asp button and the bootstrap. So I changed the cssclass to just use the style and nothing more and I got it working. Thanks for the link as, its a good visual aid.